# Matlab : Local colour histogram with trilinear interpolation

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to implement colour self similarity feature for human detection. In that we have to get local colour histogram in HSV colour space with 3 bins, i.e we get a histogram of 3x3x3 dimensions. Here we have to perform trilinear interpolation to get the histogram because values might not perfectly fall into the bins. 
e.g:  If we take 3 bins the centers of the bins are [0.1667 0.5000 0.8333]. If we have pixel with 3 channels as [0.8 0.8 0.8] the we have to interpolate it vote between h(2,2,2),h(2,2,3),h(2,3,2),h(2,3,3),h(3,2,2),h(3,2,3) and h(3,3,3), where h is the histogram and h(i,j,k) refers to bin at ith center in H channel , jth center in S channel and kth center in V channel.

Is there any inbuilt function in matlab to implement CSS feature as described by Walk10cvp. Or is there any inbuilt to get this local histogram. Or is there anyway any builtin to do this interpolation (I failed in using interp3()). Any help in this respect is appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: please format your question

Comment: interp3() is the way to go. Im sorry you failed using it, but you should try harder or shows us what failed

Comment: I tried out with in RGB colour space with values between 0-255, so if i have a value of x (intensity in at a pixel in all the three channels) is between 127.5 and 212.5
>> [X,Y,Z] = meshgrid([127.500 212.5]);
>> x = 210;
>> interp3(x,x,x,1,X,Y,Z)
Error using griddedInterpolant
Interpolation requires at least two sample points in each dimension.

Error in interp3 (line 129)
        F = griddedInterpolant({X, Y, Z}, V, method,extrap);

Comment: If I am right, you are not exactly will to perform linear interpolation, but you want to find the 8 trilinear interpolation weights to add contributions to the 8 surrounding bins. This is an elementary computation.

Comment: Please don't link to paid articles, we are not going to spend money for you.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Exactly I wish to  do that

Comment: @YvesDaoust I added new link to the paper

Comment: I'm not sure it's ethical to change a paid-for-link to an article to one where you downloaded the material and shared it for free with the world

Comment: @Adriaan: this is most probably illegal. Fortunately, the link doesn't work.

Comment: @Adriaan I downloaded the pdf from the authors home page as far i remember. Even I dont have access to IEEE explore. I uploaded in my drive because i was not finding the link from which i downloaded

Comment: @YvesDaoust they'd at least appreciate a proper citation instead of a plain link. Link does work for me btb.

Comment: @Aditya: finding a document on the web does not allow you to republish it freely. Don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is elementary.

Let u and u* be the linear interpolation weights for X between X0 and X1.

We have u = (X1 - X) / (X1 - X0) and u* = (X - X0) / (X1 - X0).

To get the trilinear weights, form the eight products uvw, u*vw, uv*w...